# Custom Bootstrap Typeahead

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to figure out how to use the default bootstrap type ahead to create a custom search of members in my database. The issue though is that it appears it only supports key/value and not multiple pieces of data.

The goal is to be able to have it do a search one 1 piece of data (such as last name) but as you type, it pulls in things like first name, email and a picture.

Is this achievable with the current type ahead or do you know if there is an alternative for it ?

Thanks for any info!

Comment: Do you mean you want to provide a custom HTML `template` to render?

Answer (score 1):

It supports more than just key value pairs in the response.

Have a look at their [examples page](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/), specifically the last one, Best Picture Winners.

It pulls from a remote source and supports templating.

```
$('.example-films .typeahead').typeahead([{
  name: 'best-picture-winners',
  remote: '../data/films/queries/%QUERY.json',
  prefetch: '../data/films/post_1960.json',
  template: '<p><strong>{{value}}</strong> – {{year}}</p>',
  engine: Hogan
}]);
```